# Spring Integration - How can I have a workflow split off to two channels?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-batch, configuration-files

Good morning all, I'm looking for a way to have our workflow split off to two different channels.

```
          -> C1
 A -> B ->
          -> C2
```

I am rather new to Spring as a whole and have just been working my way through things and have not been able to Google a solution.

The workflow that I have uses an int-file to read in the source data and passes them off to various channels such as A - B but I need to be able to send all of my data off to two unique channels that do entirely different things.

What sort of tags or topics are to be used in order for me to have the full data sent off to each of the C1/C2 channels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this purpose you need to use a *recipient list router* EI pattern: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/RecipientList.html

Spring Integration has an implementation on the matter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#router-implementations-recipientlistrouter

So, you have a single `input-channel` and you configure a `recipient` for each channel you would like to distribute the same message.

The Loan Broker sample has some configuration on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/applications/loan-broker

The Java DSL variant is described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#java-dsl-routers

Comment: Thank you for the references. The RecipientListRouter is what I'm needing.